# Embed param with index page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to embed a parameter with all my pages url. Like:

index page = `www.abc.com?param=value`

about us page = `www.abc.com/about-us.html?param=value`

When i google it I found param tag. But it is child tag of Object Tag. So I don't know how to use this to address my issue.

Note: Am adding parameter to maintain my version upgrades so that browser will fetch from server whenever new updates added not fetching from cache like Google.

How to achieve that?

Comment: You have provided two valid URLs already. Your idea is correct: by providing a changeable value in your URLs you will be able to force browsers to look for "fresh content" (at least each time the value changes). But what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

> When i google it I found param tag. But it is child tag of Object Tag. So I don't know how to use this to address my issue.

You can't. It has nothing to do with your issue. Object parameters and query string parameters are entirely unrelated.

> Am adding parameter to maintain my version upgrades so that browser will fetch from server whenever new updates added not fetching from cache like Google.

That is used when linking to resources that change infrequently and you normally want to be heavily cached, but which occasionally change in a way that would break parts of a site if not refreshed in the browser. Primarily this applies to stylesheets and JavaScript files.

For regular pages, you usually don't want such strict caching rules so you should configure your HTTP server to put appropriate cache control headers in the HTTP response for the HTML document.

For instance:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=3600
ETag:"44ab-51ae9454a67e2"
```

[mnot has a good guide](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) if you want a more in depth explanation about how to control caching.